# Cannot load Counter Name data because an invalid index -Exception

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2012

I am using C# and WPF - Operating System is windows 7 Professional and Visual Studio 2012, SQL Server 2012.

I used Devexpress Grid in wpf. I want to bind it to database using ADO.Net Server mode. I selected "Items Source Wizard" Option to do this binding but it generated following Exception:

> InvalidOperationException: Cannot load Counter Name data because an invalid index '' was read from the registry.

**What does this exception mean?**

Can you please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks,
Annie.

Answer (score 121):

Although this has already been answered, I see people are repeatedly getting the same error that I did when trying to solve it. If when you run:

`C:\windows\system32> lodctr /r`

you get the error

`Error: Unable to rebuild performance counter setting from system backup store, error code is 2`

then you instead need to run

`C:\windows\SysWOW64> lodctr /r`

after which you should get

`Info: Successfully rebuilt performance counter setting from system backup store`

Note this has to be done as administrator. I found the solution [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/9b01e1a6-d872-4f28-9280-f35d6ca02a9f/lodctr-r-error-code-2?forum=w7itprogeneral)

Comment: Yep, first time error --  Second time resolved  C:\Windows\system32>lodctr /r

Error: Unable to rebuild performance counter setting from system backup store, error code is 2
C:\Windows\system32>lodctr /r

Info: Successfully rebuilt performance counter setting from system backup store

Comment: I had same problem while running SSIS package. Executing lodctr /r solved the problem.

Comment: 3 years after last post, 6 years after question, I had this error on a Windows 7 machine trying to run Intel Processor Diagnostics Tool (IPDT). The fix(es) worked. Thanks!

Comment: I did not have the folder `SysWOW64`, but running it from `C:\Windows>` solved the issue!

Answer (score 104):

Just had that message related to Microsoft Dynamics CRM updates not installing and [the marked answer for this post](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/perfmon-problems-unable-to-add-counters/e90f231d-0014-457d-8b1f-5f342971597a) helped greatly:

> Click Start, type cmd right click cmd.exe, and select Run as administrator.
>   At the prompt, type **lodctr /r** and press ENTER.

Apparently, Windows keeps some counters cache in the registry at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Perflib\009` \ `Counter`+`Help`. If this cache becomes corrupted (has blank lines), you get the above errors - and `lodctr /r` rebuilds that cache.

Comment: I get: "Error: Unable to rebuild performance counter setting from system backup store, error code is 5PS"

Comment: @tdc you need to run from an elevated prompt

Comment: @tdc, you have to close VS or in my case, close the ui recording in the down right edge of your screen

Answer (score 13):

1. Go to Start, type `cmd`.
2. Right-click on `cmd.exe` and choose ‘Run as administrator’.
3. Type `lodctr /r` and press enter.

You will then get the message `‘Info: Successfully rebuilt performance counter setting from system backup store’`.

4. Check if there are providers that are disabled, write `lodctr /q` and press enter
5. You will then get a long list of providers, make sure that the `[CRM Client]` is `Enabled`, see below

If not, write `lodctr /e:CRM Client` and press enter.

6. Install the Microsoft Dynamics CRM for Outlook client Update Rollup

Answer (score 1):

1. Run command prompt as admin.
2. Type `LODCTR /r`
3. Wait a few seconds to discard it Error: Unable to reset the performance counter from the system backup storage. Error code 2.

Retype `LODCTR / r` this time it is working successfully.