# CosmosDB crashing on launch GatewayServiceStartup

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, document-database

Just installed CosmosDB emulator 1.19 and ran into issues upon startup. GatewayServiceStartup stops working upon launch. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Hi, any progress now?

Answer (score 0):

You could debug the GatewayServiceStartup process and check the log.

> If you experience crashes in CosmosDB.StartupEntryPoint.exe, run the
>   following command from an admin command prompt: lodctr /R

You could find the above statement in the **Troubleshooting Chapter** from this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator#troubleshooting).

In addition , please refer to the thread:
[documentdb emulator gatewayservice crashing on startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41992585/documentdb-emulator-gatewayservice-crashing-on-startup).

Hope it helps you.