# Errors when launching Cosmos DB Emulator

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-compute-emulator

I tried to launch Cosmos DB Emulator, but I get these 3 errors:

- DocumentDb Master has stopped working
- DocumentDb.GatewayService.exe has stopped working
- DocumentDb Server has stopped working

[image: Error pop-ups]

Answer (score 1):

I think it was the problem about GatewayServiceStartup process.

To solve this, we can try to run the elevated command:

```
C:\windows\SysWOW64> lodctr /r
```

This problem is most often caused by incompatibility with local SQL server.

The familiar issue as yours: [documentdb emulator gatewayservice crashing on startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41992585/documentdb-emulator-gatewayservice-crashing-on-startup)

In addition, we can refer to the troubleshooting Chapter from this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator#troubleshooting) for more information.

Hope it is helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can download emulator from Microsoft **[`Download Center`](https://aka.ms/cosmosdb-emulator)**.Extract setup and run emulator exe.

Once you completed the setup, type Azure Cosmos DB Emulator in Start menu. Run it as administrator

If you are stuck at any point read **[Here](http://sajeetharan.blogspot.com/2018/03/setting-up-azure-cosmos-db-with-visual.html)**

Comment: @GauravMantri sorry Running as admin should solve the issue, link is corrected now

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and gave up. Accidentally I found the solution after ([AzureStorageEmulator 5.1 doesn't to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60280401/azurestorageemulator-5-1-doesnt-to-start)):

*seems, I found the reason - the net access for local machine was closed somehow:( I have ran the command*

```
netsh http add iplisten 127.0.0.1
```