# AzureStorageEmulator 5.1 doesn't to start

Tags: azure

After my Win10 update the AzureStorageEmulator (5.10.0.0) embedded into VS2019 (16.4.5) doesn't to start. I have tried to start it separately, but the same problem

```
AzureStorageEmulator.exe start -inprocess
Windows Azure Storage Emulator 5.10.0.0 command line tool
Service Status: Blob http://127.0.0.1:10000/ False
The network location cannot be reached. For information about network troubleshooting, see Windows Help
Error: Unable to start the storage emulator.
```

I tried in addition to initialize AzureStorage

```
AzureStorageEmulator.exe init
Windows Azure Storage Emulator 5.10.0.0 command line tool
Found SQL Instance (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB.
Creating database AzureStorageEmulatorDb510 on SQL instance '(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB'.
Granting database access to user EVN-TEAMVIEWER\simon.hunanyan.
Database access for user EVN-TEAMVIEWER\simon.hunanyan was granted.
Initialization successful. The storage emulator is now ready for use.
The storage emulator was successfully initialized and is ready to use.
```

But the result the same:(

Maybe somebody already bumped to this problem? Any idea - how to resolve it?

Comment: Please check if port 10000 is available and not used by another process/application.

Comment: I had to start a command prompt as an admin to be able to launch the emulator.  That was not necessary a couple of weeks ago if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 11):

seems, I found the reason  - the net access for local machine was closed somehow:(
I have ran the command

```
netsh http add iplisten 127.0.0.1
```

and surprisingly AzureStorageEmulator was started

```
AzureStorageEmulator.exe start -inprocess
Windows Azure Storage Emulator 5.10.0.0 command line tool
Service Status: Blob http://127.0.0.1:10000/ True
Service Status: Queue http://127.0.0.1:10001/ True
Service Status: Table http://127.0.0.1:10002/ True
```

Comment: super time saver tip

Comment: thank you buddy. I wished i had stumbled upon this 3 hours ago...