# Can't get the CPU Usage in C# using PerformanceCounter - System.FormatException

Tags: c#, .net, cpu-usage, performancecounter, formatexception

I always used this simple code (from [#278071](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278071/how-to-get-the-cpu-usage-in-c)) to get CPU usage:

```
var cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total");

public string getCurrentCpuUsage() {
        return cpuCounter.NextValue()+"%";
}
```

It worked perfectly for years. But it's not working after upgrade. I'm using Windows 10 now and cpuCounter.NextValue throws **System.FormatException**: Input string was not in a correct format.

What's wrong? Is it because of Windows 10? Or it's because of my new CPU - Xeon E5-2683? How can I get the CPU usage?

**upd:**
System.FormatException is thrown when I'm using .NET Framework 3.5. I switched to .NET Framework 4.5 and now it throws **InvalidOperationException**: Cannot load Counter Name data because an invalid index '' was read from the registry.

Comment: Is it `cpuCounter.NextValue()` that throws the error, or `cpuCounter.NextValue()+"%"`?

Comment: cpuCounter.NextValue();
cpuCounter.NextSample() throws exception too.

Comment: Works on my win10 machine, so it is probably not that. Code seems fine.

Comment: The question you linked is 10 years old. The links in the linked answer points to documentation of .Net version 2.0 . What is your .Net version ? Can you check for your answer in the corresponding documentation version ?

Comment: Just updated question.

Comment: Problem solved.

Answer (score 4):

Solution: [Cannot load Counter Name data because an invalid index -Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980178/cannot-load-counter-name-data-because-an-invalid-index-exception)

Just run "lodctr /r" as Administrator. Everything is fine now.